# Programming & running Windows files under Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to program or run Windows executables under Linux not using wine when a Windows is already installed on the computer?

I mean from what I heard wine does nothing but download the Windows libraries and use those to emulate a windows environment to run programs. I find it much more comfortable to use what there is already instead of downloading it a second time.

I also don't want to write all the code again but instead just tell e.g. Qt or gcc to use the Windows files instead of linux files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine does not download Windows dlls, it does reimpement the apis. Therefore to run Windows Applications you have to either use something like Wine or a Virtual Machine.

BTW: Question would fit better on superuser.com

BTW2: If it is about programming: you can try to use frameworks like Mono and compile for the different OS.

Comment: So there's no other way to use the Windows files to run Windows executables on my computer?  
BTW: half of the question would.  
BTW2: I'm currently using Qt which is a cross platform API. However I yet still don't know how to compile Windows executables instead of Linux executables and I thought it would be possible to somehow reference the Windows files that are lying on the computer.

Comment: Usually Linux uses a binary format ELF, Windows PXE, which are incompatible to each other. You would need a layer which can read the binary format of the other plattform. Even if you could reference it, things in the dll won't normally be compatible (think about syscalls etc.pp.). Therefore you either need a reimplementation like Wine or an Emulator or a VM. As Wine reimplements Windows Apis you won't even be sure if a program which is running in Wine runs the same way on Windows. If it is about testing a programm therefore the best way is to use a real Windows. (VM can hide timing problems)

Comment: On the other hand: you don't need to write code a second time, just compile it on the other plattform (if everything in code is plattform independend)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was planning however the compiler is not working on my other computer for some reason. Thus I thought I could compile Windows executables without restarting the computer to switch to windows and vice versa every time. Oh well. Thanks anyways.